# Jess bind this instance of java object

Tags: jess

I want to do something like that in Jess:

```
(bind ?instance (this))
```

The only way I get it working is by using "new Object" instead of "this".

How can I get it working?

Comment: The Java keyword this doesn't make sense in Jess, where you never are in the non-static context of a Java class. What do you want to do here?

Comment: I just want a reference to the object that calls the Rete.run() method, instead of searching for such an object of that class (which is singleton anyway) within Jess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are passing some Jess code to the Rete.exec() method, and want a reference to the object that's making the call. You just have to inject it into Jess yourself. Either use Rete.store() to store the object in Jess, then use (fetch) to retrieve it from storage in the Jess code, or use the methods of the global context object -- see Rete.getGlobalContext() -- to set a variable to refer to the Java object, then use the variable in the Jess code.

Comment: Well I wasn't even aware of the exec method. The thing is I have an AI bot class and I want to run the Rete engine in every call of it's logic() method (assuming my thinking is corrent and that is the correct way to run the engine within it). I wanted to pass the reference of the bot to Jess so I have access to it's variables and methods, but I figured later that instead of that I should just do engine.add(this). With my limited understanding of Jess, I won't have to use any Jess methods in java, like exec or eval etc. Am I right about this?

Comment: My answer still applies; before calling run(), use one of the methods I described to tell Jess about your object, and the corresponding technique in Jess code to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's three ways you can access a Pojo from the Jess environment, and a fourth if it is a singleton.

```
public class Main {
    public static Main theInstance;
    public static Main getInstance(){ return theInstance; }
    private String user = "Joe";
    public String getUser(){ return user; }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        Main.theInstance = main;
        Rete rete = new Rete();
        // as a global
        Defglobal glob = new Defglobal( "*main*", new Value( main ) );
        glob.reset( rete );
        // as a store member
        rete.store( "main", main );
        // as a fact
        rete.add( main );
        // execute demo clp
        rete.batch( "two.clp" );
    }
}
```

And the .clp is:

```
(printout t "?*main* = " ?*main* crlf)
(printout t "?*main*.user = " (?*main* getUser) crlf)
(printout t "main = " (fetch main)  crlf)
(printout t "main.user = " ((fetch main) getUser) crlf)
(defrule get-main-user
    (Main (user ?user))
=>
    (printout t "a Main(slot user) = " ?user crlf)
)
(run)
(printout t "Main.theInstance = " ((call Main getInstance) getUser) crlf)
```

Output:

```
?*main* = <Java-Object:Main>
?*main*.user = Joe
main = <Java-Object:Main>
main.user = Joe
a Main(slot user) = Joe
Main.theInstance = Joe
```